# Jquery: adding img and video to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

I am building an image gallery using photoswipe (http://photoswipe.com/), but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to add videos to the array. Below's my HTML:

```
div class="gallery">


    <figure class="photo" role="img">
    <div class="content">
      <a href="https://photo.page">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/900/?image=702" data-caption="Sea side, south shore<br><em class='text-muted'>© Dominik Schröder</em>" data-width="1200" data-height="900" itemprop="thumbnail" data-permalink="http://google.com" alt="Image description" data-title="title2">
      </a>
    </div>  
    </figure>


    <figure class="photo" role="img">
    <div class="content">
      <a href="https://photo.page">

      <video width="100%" data-width="248" data-height="146" data-permalink="http://google.com" data-title="title" data-caption="Test" autoplay muted>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>

      </a>
      </div>
```

And here's my JS:

```
(function($) {

  // Init empty gallery array
  var container = [];

  // Loop over gallery items and push it to the array
  $('.gallery').find('figure').each(function() {
    var $link = $(this).find('img, video'), 
      item = {
        src: $link.attr('src'),
        w: $link.data('width'),
        h: $link.data('height'),
        title: $link.data('caption'),
        pid: $link.data('title'),
        attachmentURL: $link.data('permalink')
      };
    container.push(item);
  });

  // Define click event on gallery item
  $('img').click(function(event) {

    // Prevent location change
    event.preventDefault();

    // Define object and gallery options
    var $pswp = $('.pswp')[0],
      options = {
        index: $(this).parents('figure').index(),
        bgOpacity: 0.9,
        showHideOpacity: true,
      };
    // Initialize PhotoSwipe
    var gallery = new PhotoSwipe($pswp, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, container, options);
    gallery.init();
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Here's a pen if it's easier: https://codepen.io/NordStorm/pen/Kqbpaj

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I noticed you finding img and video `var $link = $(this).find('img, video'),` change this to `var $link = $(this).find('video'),`. it will work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code. You have used `figure` for each loop it will loop every `figure` element.

```
'use strict';

/* global jQuery, PhotoSwipe, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, console */

(function($) {

  // Init empty gallery array
  var container = [];

  // Loop over gallery items and push it to the array
  $('.gallery').find('figure video').each(function() {
    var $link = $(this), 
      item = {
        src: $link.attr('src'),
        w: $link.data('width'),
        h: $link.data('height'),
        title: $link.data('caption'),
        pid: $link.data('title'),
        attachmentURL: $link.data('permalink')
      };

    container.push(item);
  });

  // Define click event on gallery item
  $('img').click(function(event) {

    // Prevent location change
    event.preventDefault();

    // Define object and gallery options
    var $pswp = $('.pswp')[0],
      options = {
        index: $(this).parents('figure').index(),
        bgOpacity: 0.9,
        showHideOpacity: true,
      };
    // Initialize PhotoSwipe
    var gallery = new PhotoSwipe($pswp, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, container, options);
    gallery.init();
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. There are a couple of issues with this: this seems to only add the video to the array, but I want both images and videos. Also, when I click on the video, I'm getting an error about not being able to load.

Comment: PhotoSwipe will not support videos.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try switching to fancyBox3, you can easily mix images and videos (and, actually, any html content).